# Get a pixel's alpha value of a png image?

Tags: php, image, png, alpha

I am using the following code:

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng("image.png");
$col = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y);
$alpha = (($col >> 24) & 0x7F);
```

but the alpha value is always 127, even if the pixel at `($x,$y)` is transparent in the original image.

Comment: And... how is that a problem? `127` means fully transparent, `0` means fully opaque.

Answer (score 0):

ya you right , you may have confused with html canvas alpha ranges

when working on php side your alpha will be always 0 to 127  # 0 mean non transparent  and 127 mean transparent

when working with front end HTML canvas your alpha range will be 0  to 255  # 0 mean Transparent & 255 mean non transparent