# PHP: combining images as layers, casting a shadow?

Tags: php, image

I'm creating a program to create a product image based on choices made by the customer. The product is men's tights, with or without codpiece, with or without feet, in three different styles.

To do this, I have seventeen PNG images: background, a pair of actual feet, torso and arms above the waist (all in color); leg options all in grayscale: right leg, left leg, right codpiece, left codpiece, etc., colorized as they're laid in.

Here is the specific issue I'm trying to work out: every image is transparent (except the background) and they layer up just fine. However, the codpiece casts a shadow on the leg: right now that shadow is a black gradient fading to transparent. Combined with the picture below it, the shadow becomes a large stain (see below).

I have google-d like crazy and tried everything I can think of, but I can't find the right combination of functions. Is what I want to do possible, and if so, how?

tl;dr: How do I get one image to cast a shadow on another?

```
    // image paths are stored in an array, built based on customer choices
    $dest = imagecreatefrompng("./layers/{$layers[0][0]}.png");
    
    for($i = 0; $i < count($layers); $i++){

        imagealphablending($dest, false);
        imagesavealpha($dest, true);

        $src = imagecreatefrompng("./layers/{$layers[$i][0]}.png");

        // apply color to the current image as appropriate
        $color = $colors[$layers[$i][1]] ?? '';
        if($color != ''){
            colorize($src, $color);
        }

        // lay the current image onto the image we're building
        imagecopymerge_alpha($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4000, 4000, 100);
    }
```

[image: codpiece with shadow]
[image: right leg]
[image: left leg]
[image: a completed image]

Comment: I'd go back to the customer and ask for an image without the artificial shadow, otherwise you'd have to work around their problem everytime. Or you could remove the shadow manually with a tool like GIMP.

Comment: To remove the dropshadow, you could replace every partially transparent pixel with a fully transparent one. Part of that solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883594/get-a-pixels-alpha-value-of-a-png-image).